# Issue with Installing angular-epub-viewer@0.1.4: Unsupported Engine Errors

Tags: angular, npm, installation, compatibility, epub

I'm currently facing issues while trying to install the angular-epub-viewer package (version 0.1.4) in my Angular project. The package installation fails with multiple "Unsupported engine" errors. Here's the error message I'm encountering:
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
...
}
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/azza/FirstStep/node_modules/autoprefixer
npm ERR! dest /home/azza/FirstStep/node_modules/.autoprefixer-VkmZJvk8
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/azza/FirstStep/node_modules/autoprefixer' -> '/home/azza/FirstStep/node_modules/.autoprefixer-VkmZJvk8'
I'm using Node.js version v16.13.2 and npm version 8.1.2. According to the documentation of the package, it should support Node.js version 14 || >=16.14, so I'm unsure why I'm facing these compatibility errors.

I've tried various solutions such as clearing the npm cache, creating a new directory, and reinstalling the package, but the issue persists.

Is there a way to resolve these unsupported engine errors and successfully install the angular-epub-viewer package?

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!